# Stepper Motor spinning twice when should be spinning once

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm trying to make a stepper motor spin exactly 90 degrees. There are 200 steps for one spin but when I do this it spins twice.

I am using the L293D motor driver ([Found here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NBQVYLL)), with a Creality 42-40 stepper motor

Here's my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
coil_A_1_pin = 4
coil_A_2_pin = 17
coil_B_1_pin = 23
coil_B_2_pin = 24
 
# adjust if different
StepCount = 8
Seq = [
[1,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,0],
[0,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,1]
]
 
GPIO.setup(enable_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_A_2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_1_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(coil_B_2_pin, GPIO.OUT)
 
GPIO.output(enable_pin, 1)
 
def setStep(w1, w2, w3, w4):
    GPIO.output(coil_A_1_pin, w1)
    GPIO.output(coil_A_2_pin, w2)
    GPIO.output(coil_B_1_pin, w3)
    GPIO.output(coil_B_2_pin, w4)
 
def forward(delay, steps):
    for i in range(steps):
        for j in range(StepCount):
            setStep(Seq[j][0], Seq[j][1], Seq[j][2], Seq[j][3])
            time.sleep(delay)
 
def backwards(delay, steps):
    for i in range(steps):
        for j in reversed(range(StepCount)):
            setStep(Seq[j][0], Seq[j][1], Seq[j][2], Seq[j][3])
            time.sleep(delay)

def spin90():
    forward(1/1000, 50)

spin90()
```

spin90() is supposed to spin it 90 degrees but spins it 180 degrees

(I didn't know to post this here or Stack overflow)

Comment: Did you try and "single (half-) step" it?

Comment: (Your signal sequence seems to leave all coils without current temporarily.)

Comment: You can't do half a step. I tried that :( What do you mean all coils are left without current? The 1 means there's a current and all of them have a 1 (I'm sort of new to this so correct me if I'm wrong on this)

Comment: `The 1 means there's a current` Put such information in your question post, better yet: present your setup (what is connected to pins 4, 17, 23, 24, what to the pins of the L293D): My *seems* was from assuming the bits/pins driving half-bridges (the L293 consists of four of them), with *coils connected between adjacent ones*, and each 1 meaning one motor terminal driven to \$V_{motor} +/V_S\$, each 0 meaning to \$V_{motor} -/GND\$ . Or identify the material you are trying to follow.

Comment: See also [EE@SE posts tagged raspberry-pi and stepper-(motor or driver)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stepper-motor+or+stepper-driver+raspberry-pi).

Comment: You should read the datasheets of the driver and the motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as presented, the `forward()` routine drives the pins `steps` times through just half of the sequence (4 array indices out of 8).
(The `backwards()` routine uses the *same sequence of states*: It should result in the motor turning in the same direction, if at all.)

One full step is from, say, index 3 to index 5 in one direction, to index 1 in the other.
Going through all 8 indices *once* should result in ***4** full steps*.
(I'm guessing going from "states" 0 to 3 gets the rotor moving in one direction, and inertia takes it to the next angular position for "state 0" where you let that follow state 3.)

You can't just start at the same index for every call to `forward()`:
You need a (angular) position variable.
If you want to keep using a "state table", initialise to, say 0.
Increment for one direction, decrement for the other.
Use the least significant three bits to index "the half-step state table" (two bits for full step).

You can do without a table keeping the "phase state" itself and "rotate" it through the variable/register - left for one direction, right for the other. Use the, say, least significant four bits for the four pins.

Note how the pattern differs in just one bit between adjacent indices, including 7↔0:
*One* `GPIO.output()` should be enough for each half-step instead of four.